# editable preg_match_all via input

Tags: php, preg-match-all

Hi how can i make preg_match_all editable

```
preg_match_all('{(".$limit.")}i',$content,$matches);

<input type="text" size="30" name="limit" id="limit" value="" />
```

so if i want to search for a different string i just need to enter in the input form?

Comment: Ah, this is a little complexer than you think, you have to pass variables from the client to PHP. Thus you have to use a form with a method (POST/GET).

Comment: yes i know, everything works fine but im using preg_match_all('{(test)}i',$content,$matches); so i want to make it editable, will it works if add another     if (($_POST['limit'])!="") {
        $limit=($_POST['limit']);

Comment: Well as simple as: `if(isset($_POST["limit"])){$limit = $_POST["limit"];}else{$limit = 1;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're using the wrong quotes for the expression string
2. You're using the expression delimiter in the wrong way, it has to be one char (*not* '{' and '}').
3. You should use [preg_quote()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) for the input for escaping special characters used by the regular expression's grammar.
4. Retrieve `$limit` from the `$_GET` superglobal array if you haven't already done.

```php
if (isset($_GET['limit'])) {
  $limit = preg_quote($_GET['limit'], '%');
  preg_match_all('%('.$limit.')%i',$content,$matches);
}
```

You also need a form for submitting the value - as HamZa said in a comment:

```html
<form action="this-script.php" method="get">
  <input type="text" size="30" name="limit" id="limit" value="" />
</form>
```

Comment: You're welcome. But please add more information (error messages or what does not work) to your question the next time ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you often use user input in your patterns, you could look at [T-Regx tool](https://t-regx.com) which has a builder for patterns! And also has automatic delimiters

```
$pattern = Pattern::inject('%(@limit)%', [
    'limit' => $_GET['limit']
]);

$pattern->match($string)->forEach(function (Match $m) {
    // do something with $m
});
```

[`Pattern::inject()`](https://t-regx.com/docs/pattern-building) (or [`Pattern::prepare()`](https://t-regx.com/docs/pattern-building)) will quote any user input.